# Doing math within a column of a dataframe or numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing, slice

I have data that I need to do simple math on but it is all in the same column. Here is what my data might look like

[image]

I need to do something like (A4+A5)-(A2+A3), then continue the pattern on each row. For example, my formula would be something like (A5+A6)-(A3+A4). I have been thinking about how to do this for a week almost and I cannot figure it out. What is the best way to go about this? I think my best bet would be to transpose the data and then work with it from there?

Thank you

Edit: ok I have come up with something that I think will work but I am not completely sure I am thinking of this right. Here is a code snippet. assuming the said data is in a numpy array starting with index 0, this would do the job right?

```
for x in range(len(list24)):
try:
    filt = ((list24[x+2]+list24[x+3])-(list24[x]+list24[x+1]))
    fraser.append(filt)
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You can always create additional columns for the intermediate steps. Use shift() for stuff on different rows.

Comment: `(df[5:-1]+df[6:])-(df[3:-3]+df[4:-2])`?

Comment: My expected output would be a new Column in the data frame of the value outputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like convolution to me. Scipy is your best bet for fast convolution. In your case you want to multiply with `[-1, -1, 1, 1]`
That means every element in the list is multiplied and summed with the weights `[-1,-1,1,1]` That is: `-1 * l[x] -1 * l[x+1] +1 * l[x+2] +1 * l[x+3]` For every x.

That is what convolution does. It is used in signal processing (finite response filter) and image processing (blurring / sharpening) all the time.

[scipy convolution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html)

I tested it. The result is exactly what your code does and a lot faster for large lists. On a list with 10000 elements the scipy version takes 291 µs, whereas your code needs 115 ms. That's a 400 times speed improvement. (For small lists, your code is faster).

with a list:
`l = [5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5, 6, 7, 8]`

you do:

```
>>> from scipy.signal import convolve

>>> f = [1, 1, -1, -1]  # the filter needs to be written backwards due to convention so instead of [-1,-1,1,1] -> [1,1,-1,-1]
>>> c = convolve(l, f, mode='valid')

>>> c
array([4,  0,  -4,  0, 4,  0,  -4,  0, 4,  0,  -4,  0, 4])
```

vs your code:

```
>>> c = []
>>> for x in range(len(l)):
...    try:
...        filt = ((l[x+2]+l[x+3])-(l[x]+l[x+1]))
...        c.append(filt)
...    except IndexError:
...        pass

>>> c
[4, 0, -4, 0, 4, 0, -4, 0, 4, 0, -4, 0, 4]
```

Oh. and to get a list back from the array c, you do:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> c = c.tolist()
>>> c

[4, 0, -4, 0, 4, 0, -4, 0, 4, 0, -4, 0, 4]
```

Update: I did some timing tests on this. I also discovered that there is a numpy implementation. That one is actually faster than scipy, especially for very few samples. Scipy is faster around 40 samples.
[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you, I did not know it had a name, that would have made my life a lot easier. I am applying a Fraser filter to VLF data if you have any idea what that is. I guess it is just a convolution filter.

Comment: No problem! Make sure you apply the filter backwards like i have it in the code. Due to convention the filter needs to be given to the convolution function backwards (everywhere, not just python). Also, I ran some speed tests. It turns out that your solution is faster for less than 1000 points. There is some overhead in the scipy function.

Comment: Oh good to know. I am mostly applying this to datasets of 20 to 100 points. I will just make an if statement based on the length of data, that should take care of performance issues incase others want to use it.

Comment: I ran a speed test, see my updated comment. There is another version from numpy, which is actually faster than yours for more than 10 data points. Scipy is faster for more than 30 data points.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this worked. I turned the values into a numpy array and did the following

```
fraser = []
      for x in range(len(list24)):
    try:
        filt = ((list24[x+2]+list24[x+3])-(list24[x]+list24[x+1]))
        fraser.append(filt)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

The index error is because eventually it will get to a point where the calculation is out of index